# Winforms, Invokes and a problematic button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, invoke

I am trying to build a chat, basically i used the invoke function what a thread.
I am able to read what the server sends me, but i am able to write only once. i am trying to finish this but not sure how to write to server each time the server:
(take into account that i wrote this before in console application form and the server works fine... i.e. the problem isnt with the server).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Click += button1_Click;
    }
    StreamReader sr;
    StreamWriter sw;
    TcpClient connection;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5000);
        sr = new StreamReader(connection.GetStream());
        sw = new StreamWriter(connection.GetStream());

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread t2 = new Thread(Reader);
        t2.Start(connection);
    }

    string msg;
    public void Reader(object o)
    {

        TcpClient con = o as TcpClient;
        if (con == null)
            return;
        while (true)
        {
             msg = sr.ReadLine();

             Invoke(new Action(Output));
        }
    }

    public void Output()
    {
        ChatScreen.Text = msg;//set the message on the screen
    }
    string textinput;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textinput = InputLine.Text;
        sw.WriteLine(textinput);// this thing, writes once, multiple clicks wont send a new line to the server :(..the problem is in this button
        sw.Flush();

    }


}
```

what I thought to do is to connect the button so it will be able to do multiple clicks ..e.g btn.Click()..or run a thread with invoke on the WriteLine (but my intuition says that making the button click several times would make the program work

Comment: And on the topic, are there any exceptions happening (and printed to the debug output window)?

Comment: I reseted my code to what it used to be a month ago, now it works. i get an exception in the invoke method when i close the application. is that normal?

Comment: another issue that i have is how can i create private messaging in winforms. i want to create some labels/buttons that will appear on the sidebar, you click on them, a window opens and you are able to chat only with that member!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the thread process when you close the form, if not when you try to do the invoke, it will fail because the form is disposed and it can't be used to do an invoke. You can override the dispose method to stop the reader thread or you can do it on the onclose method. Or you can check on the reader process if the control it's available (it is not disposed) and if it's not available finish the read process.

You should prevent that the reader process will be launch multiple times too, to prevent errors, so you need to disable the button when the thread is run.

Edited:

You can use something like the following code to read multiple lines and to stop the thread when you close the form.

```
   private bool mbIsRunning = true;

   private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
   {
      lock (this)
      {
         mbIsRunning= false;
      }
   }

   private bool IsRunning
   {
        get
        { 
            lock(this)
            {
                return mbIsRunning;
            }
        }
    }


    string msg;
    public void Reader(object o)
    {

        TcpClient con = o as TcpClient;
        if (con == null)
            return;
        while (IsRunning)
        {
             msg = reader.ReadLine(); 
             string line;
             while( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null )
             {
                msg = msg + Enviroment.NewLine + line;
             }

             Invoke(new Action(Output));
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am also having a problem starting a new line after each message, once it is being sent to the richTextBox that i have got..    i tried to do  \n or \r,, but didnt help

Comment: To include a new line you should use Environment.NewLine. But I can see on your code where you insert the new line, you need to do it when you include the readed text on the msgbox (but I can't see that you concat the readed text neither).

Comment: sw1[i].WriteLine(name[i] + ":  " + word2, Environment.NewLine); Thats what i did. could you tell me how to prevent teh invoke exception and stop the thread?

Comment: You have to concat the lines on the client side too, because you are reading line by line. You need to stop the process thread on the form close, you can use a flag on the process method (you can use the control as flag too) or you can use the thread abort (this is not a good option).

Comment: how does the syntax of thread abort look like?  i did this        ChatScreen.Text = msg + Environment.NewLine;  still wont start a new line

Comment: It's a thread method, you need to store the thread that you are using to process, and on this thread you use myThread.Abort(),a ThreadStateException is thrown in the thread that called Abort, you need to catch this exception and process it inside the thread. But this is not a very good option.

Answer (score 0):

Running up your code, I get a bunch of errors - from the TcpClient throwing an exception and so on.
However, assuming that you haven't posted all of your code, I would recommend putting a try...catch around all of your functions, and then breakpoints in the catch to see what the problem is. Examine the exceptions - exceptions should only be thrown in exceptional circumstances - so your code should really work without doing that.

Comment: How do i stop a thread? should i put try and catch around the invoke? and then do what in the catch?

Comment: Yes, put try...catch around the invokes etc. At run-time you can just ignore the catch result - it has stopped the exception getting propogated to where it doesn't want to go...but at debug time you could look at the exception detail which would give you information on what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I do concat on my server code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started");
            string word = "";
            savedObject saved = new savedObject();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient connection = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("connection accepted");
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(saved.ProssecClient, connection);
            }
        }
    }
}





class savedObject
{
    Dictionary<string, StreamWriter> dic = new Dictionary<string, StreamWriter>();
    StreamReader[] sr1 = new StreamReader[100];
    StreamWriter[] sw1 = new StreamWriter[100];
    string[] name = new string[100];
    int m;
    int a;
    int g;
    string word;

    public string AllWords(string sit)
    {
        word += sit + "  ";// here i concat them
        return word;
    }


    public string word2()
    {
        return word;
    }



    public void ProssecClient(object o)
    {


        TcpClient connection = o as TcpClient;
        if (connection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(connection.GetStream());
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(connection.GetStream());
        sr1[a++] = new StreamReader(connection.GetStream());
        sw1[m++] = new StreamWriter(connection.GetStream());
        string word2 = "";
        sw.WriteLine("Please, fill your name: ");
        name[g++] = sr.ReadLine();

        if (name[g] != null && sw1[m] != null)
        {
            dic.Add(name[g], sw1[m]);
        }
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int i = 0;
                word2 = AllWords(sr.ReadLine());

                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    if (sw1[i] != null)
                    {
                        sw1[i].WriteLine( name[i] + ":  " + word2);// here is the words that are sent..

                        sw1[i].Flush();

                    }

                }

            }
        }
        catch { Console.WriteLine("client left"); }
    }

}
```

Comment: On the client you are reading  line by line, so you need to concat the different lines on the client side because you want to have multiple lines on both sides (as you said on your previous comment). But do you have only this problem? The "ProssecClient" use the collection indexes without any check, and the for index too and in general the code isn't clear, I can't see the "dic" usage, I can't understand why the for is from 0 to 3, neither the usage of the members "a", "m" & "g".

Comment: The dic usage will come to use when i use private messages, i need to save the streams and names in a Dictionary. a m and g, are simply numbers, they count the spaces in an array. i save all the streams and names in an array, so that i will be able to send to all of them messages. i dont understand why cant i send the message with a command to start a new line :( or do it on the client side. simply break the line after each message arrives, sounds simple..but i cant do it